# Comparing columns and list elements for using pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` which may look like something like this

```
data = {"col_x": ["1234", "5678", "9876", "1111"],
        "col_y": ["1234", "2222", "3333", "1111"],
        "col_grp": [pd.NA, ["5678", "9999"], ["9876", "5555", "1222"], pd.NA]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to make another column `valid` to check if `col_x` equals `col_y` or `col_x` is in `col_grp`.

I tried with

```
def check_validity(row):
    if row["col_x"] == row["col_y"]:
        return True
    if pd.notnull(row["col_grp"]):
        if isinstance(row["col_grp"], list):
            return row["col_x"] in row["col_grp"]
        else:
            return row["col_x"] == row["col_grp"]
    return False

df["valid"] = df.apply(lambda row: check_validity(row), axis=1)
```

But I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know that `list` should probably not be in a `pd.DataFrame` like this, so I apologize in advance.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apply` but a list comprehension that will be more efficient:

```
df['valid'] = [x==y or isinstance(g, list ) and x in g for (x, y, g)
               in zip(df['col_x'], df['col_y'], df['col_grp'])]
```

If you must use `apply`:

```
def check_validity(row):
    x, y, g = row[['col_x', 'col_y', 'col_grp']]
    return x==y or isinstance(g, list ) and x in g

df['valid'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_validity(row), axis=1)
```

Output (with some extra rows):

```
  col_x col_y             col_grp  valid
0  1234  1234                <NA>   True
1  5678  2222        [5678, 9999]   True
2  9876  3333  [9876, 5555, 1222]   True
3  1111  1111                <NA>   True
4  1234  2222                <NA>  False
5  1234  2222              [2222]  False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_validity(row):
    if row["col_x"] == row["col_y"]:
        return True
    
    if isinstance(row["col_grp"], list):
        return row["col_x"] in row["col_grp"]
    elif pd.notnull(row["col_grp"]):
        return row["col_x"] == row["col_grp"]
    return False

df["valid"] = df.apply(check_validity, axis=1)
```

The problem is with the null checking. pd.notnull returns a list of booleans if you give it a list, not a single boolean. You can fix the issue by first checking if the cell contains a list or not. Also, the use of a lambda function there is not correct, you can give the function directly.